# Origin of 信じる, 感じる, etc?

Tags: kanji, etymology

Wikipedia claims that Japanese verbs are a closed class and that loanwords from Chinese always use する. 信じる, 感じる seems to be an exception. Why aren't they 信をする and 感をする? Maybe because one kanji is too short?

Also, what is the origin of the ending じる used with these two borrowed verbs?

Comment: There are also 略す, 愛す, etc. which are not of the form noun + を + する. Also, what's sometimes called する verb should not have the を, like 勉強する needn't be 勉強をする...

Comment: 愛す makes sense because in CJ the verb する was just す at the end of sentences right? So 愛する人 but 人は愛す? Probably a source of confusion when the two forms were merged, with somebody using the shorter す and others using する?

Comment: su is the original conclusive form (終止形) of the verb. suru is the attributive (連体形) form of it. Conclusive merged into attributive, so suru now the norm.

Comment: But the norm for the negative of 略す, for example, is 略さない rather than 略しない, no? (Similarly, 訳しない just sounds wrong to my ears...)

Comment: Never heard of 愛さない though.

Comment: Me neither, but I think 愛せない is quite standard.

Comment: ryaku su is the formal, classical form. It is a サ変 verb because su (and suru) is サ変. When conclusive merged into attributive (su -> suru), it too became ryaku suru. This is still a サ変 verb. In addition, ryaku　su was re-analyzed as a single word ryakusu. As a result, it looses the サ変 conjugation and takes on 五段. In summary, there now three forms: 1) サ変 ryaku su, 2) サ変 ryaku suru, and 3) 五段 ryakusu.

Comment: In some words (such as [閉じる](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/detail?p=%E9%96%89%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss)), じる isn't from す(る).  In these words, it's a respelling of ぢる, which, I think, comes from づ(る) (as in [閉づ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%96%89%E3%81%A5)).

Comment: Another group related to this is 〜ざる verbs, which are more or less interchangeable with 〜じる verbs (although not all 〜じる verbs appear to have a corresponding 〜ざる form.  Couldn't find 信ざる or 感ざる, for example.).  Best examples I can recall offhand are 混じる<=>混ざる and 閉じる<=>閉ざる.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-ziru is from -zuru, which in turn is verb -suru voiced due to compounding. zuru becomes ziru during the push to normalize verbs to 一段 class.

Comment: "the push to normalize verbs to 一段 class". Hmm that confused me a bit. So in a period of history, language teachers purposefully changed words to 一段?

Comment: Language teachers did not push it. Languages naturally change. I covered this topic earlier this week.

Comment: "I covered this topic earlier this week." I'm even more puzzled ^_^ where are you covering this? Japanese historical phonology I like very much.

Comment: Link: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/is-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-the-%E3%81%B0-form-of-a-verb/11393#comment23374_11393

Comment: It's still interesting that the する verbs, like 愛する seem to have regularized to 五段, while the ずる verbs regularized to 一段. That is, unless I am missing something.

Comment: 愛する are not 五段 right? IIRC nobody says 愛する　愛すります　愛すらない

Comment: 愛する is not 五段; it is サ変. But like my comment to the main question, there is 五段 愛す.

Comment: @EricDong yes, I didn't explain that well. I'm treating 愛す(る) as a regular 五段 愛す with a suppleted 終止形・連体形 愛する. I believe that's the most common modern use. Treating it as サ変 would mean that the negative is 愛しない. I've never heard that (in modern use), but I could be wrong.

Comment: 愛せない or 愛さない? If the former, then it's still サ変 using the old -nai stem.

Comment: @EricDong, nope, if it's サ変, the negative is 愛しない. Potential is 愛せない for both  五段 and サ変.

Comment: I thought CJ しない was せず?

Comment: @dainichi, I think Eric Dong is thinking of the classical / literary form for サ変, which would be せ for the *mizenkei*.  See the [JA Wikipedia article on サ変 verbs](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8#.E3.81.99.EF.BC.88.E6.96.87.E8.AA.9E.EF.BC.89).  That said, 愛す(る) is weird even as a サ変動詞, and the negative is 愛さない.  For instance, see the [JA Wiktionary entry for 愛する](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%84%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B#.E6.B4.BB.E7.94.A8), where they clearly lay out which theoretical conjugations aren't actually used.

Answer (score 5):

#### Japanese verbs as a class

The [**Word class system** section of the **Japanese grammar** Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Word_class_system) does currently state that Japanese verbs and adjectives are [closed classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_class).  Strictly speaking, I don't think this is quite correct -- closed classes don't have new members, and generally don't have many members.  Japanese verbs are quite numerous indeed, and it's not uncommon for new ones to pop up -- witness recent neologisms like [ググる "to Google"](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B0%E3%82%8B), or [スタバる "to go to Starbucks"](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%82%8B).  Sure, these are slang, but they're also new verbs.  It's also not unheard of for folks to coin new verbs by just tacking a -る on the end, such as [クッキングる "to cooking"](http://twicsy.com/i/TFW4Yc) > humorous for "to cook", or [ドライビングる "to driving"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%93%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%8B%22) > humorous for "to drive [a vehicle]".

That said, I think it would be accurate to say that *-jiru* verbs are a closed class.  These all seem to have arisen through regular sound changes from `[single kanji]` + transitive verb suffix す.

#### *Shinjiru* and other *-jiru* verbs

As an addendum to Dono's answer, Shogakukan's entries suggest that these `[single kanji]` + じる terms were originally used as verbs in Japanese by simply appending す, the transitive auxiliary verb (superseded by modern する).  This す then became ず due to [rendaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) caused by the final ん in 信{しん}, and then became ずる when the attributive and terminal forms for verbs fused, and finally became じる due to the shift to *ichidan* verbs that Dono mentions.

You can track some of this back via online resources by starting at [the Daijirin entry for 信じる](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B).  Note how it says:

- 「 信ずる 」に同じ。
  Same as *shinzuru*.

Click on 信ずる and you'll jump straight to the 信ず entry.  The second line here says:

- 「信ず」の口語形としては、サ行変格活用の動詞「信ずる」が対応する。
  The colloquial form of *shinzu* is the *sa-hen* conjugation verb *shinzuru*.

So we have a clear historical progression:

- `[single kanji ending in ん]` + す →
- `[single kanji]` + ず →
- `[single kanji]` + ずる →
- `[single kanji]` + じる

Other examples include:

案{あん}じる　　演{えん}じる　　応{おう}じる　　禁{きん}じる　　準{じゅん}じる

生{しょう}じる　　談{だん}じる　　転{てん}じる　　封{ふう}じる　　論{ろん}じる

Other terms borrowed from Chinese and used as verbs in Japanese historically took the form `[kanji term]` + す, with す again changing to する when the terminal and attributive verb forms merged.  Rendaku generally didn't happen for multi-character words ending in ん, which is why you'll only see these -じる forms for single-character on'yomi terms, and mostly (but not always) where the on'yomi ends in ん.

Comment: Shogakukan publishes quite a few dictionaries, e.g. progressive, 大辞泉, 日本国語大辞典. I'm wondering which one you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.  The Shogakukan dictionary I use most is the electronic version of the JA-JA 日本国語大辞典（新装版）, 1988.